# STATI Schengen : What does it mean

Tags: france, schengen, italy, terminology, rome

I am going to Europe for my honeymoon. My entry and exit is from Rome.

My Visa says Stati Schengen, Type C.

I understand Type C is for short term travel. Can anyone help me understand Stati means ?

I plan to visit France as well in between. I hope it will not be a problem.

Comment: It should not be a problem. I know that as an American I am allowed to visit any Schengen country without a visa for a period of 3 months, after of which I should be out of the Schengen zone for 3 months and in total only allowed to spend 6 months a year in the Schengen countries. Assuming I have not requested an extension to stay based on study or work.

Comment: “Stati” simply means “states” or “countries” in Italian. There is even a document somewhere on the EU website with a translation for this (and a few other things like “cancelled”) in all 20+ official languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Schengen Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Agreement) is an agreement between several states that created the Schengen Area within which there are little or no border or visa controls.

STATI Schengen in Italian means "Schengen countries", so those countries that are part of the Schengen Area.

You can find a list of these countries [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area).
I guess your Visa is stating that you can visit the countries that are part of the Schengen area.